# How do I prove that compositions of $C^\infty$ functions are $C^\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $G$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^\infty$ function and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^\infty$ function.

Then, how do I prove that $g\circ f$ is of $C^\infty$?

I know that $g\circ f$ is Fréchet differentiable, but it gets much harder to prove higher order differentiability of $g\circ f$.

Answer (score 3):

Proceed by induction on the degree of differentiation (and take care of *all* compositions of *all* smooth functions simultaneously for each step before you go to the next):

> For any $n$, every composition $g\circ f$ of $C^\infty$ functions $f, g$ is in $C^n$.

Base case: $n = 0$. The composition of smooth functions is continuous. This is a special case and something that should be rather obvious.

Induction step: Let $h = g\circ f$ and assume that all compositions are in $C^n$. Then $h' = f'\cdot (g'\circ f)$ is the product of a smooth function with a composition which by the induction hypothesis is in $C^n$. Therefore $h'\in C^n$, which yields $h \in C^{n+1}$.

Comment: Ok so if I can prove the lemma then everything js done. However, I'm not sure about the lemma. For instance, $D^2(fg)(p)(x,y)= D^2f(p)(x,y) g(p) + Df(p)(x)Dg(p)(y)+ Df(p)(y)Dg(p)(x) + f(p)D^2g(x,y)$. As you can see, it cannot be simply written as $D^2(fg)(p)=D^2f(p) g(p) + 2Df(p)Dg(p) + f(p)D^2g$ since the variables are independent. Could you please be more specific how the lemma can be proven? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Rubertos By $fg$ I mean the function $h(x) = f(x) \cdot g(x)$, not $h(x, y) = f(x)\cdot g(y)$. I also think you missed the main point of my induction. Prove the statement "For _any_ $f\in C^m$ and $g\in C^n$, we have $fg \in C^{\min(m, n)}$" by induction. The induction step has $$h = fg\implies h' = f'g + fg'$$ with $f'g \in C^{\min(m-1, n)}$ and $fg' \in C^{\min(m, n-1)}$. Therefore $h'\in C^{\min(m-1, n-1)} = C^{\min(m, n) - 1}$. There are quite a few indices to keep track of, but it works out in the end.

Comment: I did not miss your point. Let $V,W$ be normed spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ and $G$ be open in $V$. Let $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:G\rightarrow W$ be $n$-times Fréchet differentiable functions. Then, it can be shown that $D(fg)(p)(x)= Df(p)(x) g(p) + f(p) Dg(p)(x)$. Note that $g(p)$ is a **vector**, so it cannot be written as $D(fg)(p)= Df(p) g(p) + f(p) Dg(p)$. You cannot simply apply induction here. And the formula I wrote is exactly $D^2h(p)$ where $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$.

Comment: @Rubertos Ahh, I missed that $G\subseteq \Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Chain rule, product rule, and induction.

Comment: How exactly do you apply induction? In which form?

Comment: Note that $D(f\circ g)(p)= g'(f(p)) Df(p), $D^2(f\circ g)(p)(x,y)= g'\circ f (p) D^2 f(x,y) + g''\circ f (p) Df(p)(x) Df(p)(y)$. The form is getting really weird so induction cannot be simply applied.